# How to find the most recently accessed pdf or doc?

Tags: windows, file-io, process

How can I retrieve the location of the most recently accessed pdf files in Windows?  One approach would be to search the system for pdf files and check which of them is the most recent, but this approach will take up time for a large system. Is there a log where I can access entries by date? I would prefer to know a way to do this in JavaScript but another solutions will be helpful too.

Comment: You want the MRU (most recently used) list for the applications that open those types of files

Comment: I want the location of the most recently used pdf files

Comment: All this information is in the registry. I don't know the exact APIs to call so I am just telling you the keyword to search is MRU